# Upload files in Angular

Tags: angular

app.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
<label class="upload input-label">Upload<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
<div class="input-group other">
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" appearance="none">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection" >
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let name of addedFiles" (removed)="remove(name)">
        {{name}}
        <!--<button matChipRemove>-->
          <mat-icon matChipRemove >cancel</mat-icon>
        <!--</button>-->
      </mat-chip>
      <!--<input [matChipInputFor]="chipList"-->
             <!--[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"-->
             <!--[matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"-->
             <!--(matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">-->
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile" (change)="filesData($event , $event)" multiple  style="display:none">
      <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile">choose files</label>
    </mat-chip-list>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
addedFiles = [];

filesData(files, event): void {
if (event.target.files.length > 5) {
  this.alertService.error("Only 5 files are allowed");

  event.preventDefault();
  event.value = ""; // clear the older value

  console.log(this.addedFiles);
} else if(event.target.files.length <=5){
  for(let file of event.target.files){
    this.addedFiles.push(file.name)
  }
  event.value ="";
}
```

}

In the above code i have added limit for uploading up to 5 files at a time. But if i add one by one file multiple times it is adding unlimited files. I need to upload only 5 files  whether i had one by one or 5 by 5.
Thanks.

Comment: Make a variable that's counting up. So if you upload 3 files at once, make the variable 3, if another file is uploaded make it 4. If the uploaded file-count + the already uploaded files > 5 throw an error.

Comment: You can't control this on Frontend. You should keep count in your Database to check how many files user have uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just count length of addedFiles array. Like this:

```
addedFiles = [];

filesData(files, event): void {
    if (this.addedFiles.length < 5) {
        for(let file of event.target.files){
            if(this.addedFiles.length < 5) {
                this.addedFiles.push(file.name);
            } else {
                this.alertService.error("Only 5 files are allowed");

                event.preventDefault();
                event.value = ""; // clear the older value
                break;
            }
        }
        event.value ="";
    } else {
        this.alertService.error("Only 5 files are allowed");

        event.preventDefault();
        event.value = ""; // clear the older value
    }
}
```

Comment: If i add more than 1 file i am getting error that only five files allowed

Comment: @bhargavi I've made a typo, fixed it now. Please try again.